# First communion, then communism?

Tags: humor

On a slightly more serious note, what do you call a kid who goes to his first communion?

Surely not a *communist*, right?

Comment: Communion initiate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No -- but perhaps a *communionist?*  :-)

Actually, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Communion , the term is *first communicant.*

Comment: +1 someone who partakes in the holy communion is a communicant.

Comment: -1 That wiki entry does not seem to have the word *communionist*. Check other sources instead.

Comment: @Kris - Try reading my post again -- ***carefully*** this time, without rushing through the first two lines. (Oh, wait -- there ***are*** only two lines.)

Comment: Wouldn't "new communicant" be better?  I would take first communicant to be the first person doing communion, not a person taking communion for the first time.

Comment: It's a part of Catholic jargon.  It doesn't matter if your version is "better".

Answer (score 4):

The one who attends communion is known as communicant. source--http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/communicant?s=t

Comment: Hence the answer is as is already given [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/169888/2022)

Comment: I am a slow typist ;)

Comment: In this case, proper etiquette is to remove your answer.

Comment: @TylerH: since when? The two answers are **not** identical, and fastest <> best. In my book, this answer is actually better, since it gives a link to an authoritative dictionary, rather than to Wikipedia.

Comment: @Marthaª Since StackExchange was a thing. And the answers **are** identical; they are both essentially link-only answers that direct the OP to the definition of communicant. Also, dictionary.com is hardly more authoritative than Wikipedia. On StackExchange sites, it's poor etiquette to provide the same answer as someone else if they've answered before you. In the event that you both answer at the same time, then you should delete your answer.

Comment: @TylerH, dictionary.com is not user-editable, therefore it **is** more authoritative than Wikipedia. And apparently, you're operating under a different definition of "identical" than I am.

Comment: @Marthaª Just because something isn't publicly editable doesn't make it authoritative. If I make a static webpage proclaiming that gravity is a myth, then by your criterion my webpage is more authoritative than Wikipedia. And these two answers are identical because one answer says "communicant" and the other answer also says "communicant".

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an English language stack exchange, I'll answer from the linguistic perspective.

Both have their etymological root in the same concept of bringing things together. Whether you are commuting to work (joining your workplace), a communist (joining a social community), or entering into a religious communion (joining with a church, and supposedly with its mythological deity).

The noun for someone who enters into religious communion is communicant.

Answer (score 0):

The three sacraments of Initiation

- baptism
- confirmation
- communion

Of the three, Communion is the only one that is received repeatedly. The first communion is the initiation to the sacrament of Communion. And the child is the initiate to the sacrament.

Comment: I guess +Kowal is more correct, in addressing the child as first communicant.

Comment: Which three sacraments of what 'Initiation'? I believe the RC Church holds that there are 7 sacraments. Biblically, one finds 2, unless 'baptisms' is subdivided and/or marriage, layings on of hands to confer office ... are similarly labelled.

Comment: They are similarly labelled.  I don't remember the details, but they're easy to look up.

Comment: These are Catholic sacraments, note; other religions parse differently.